# Doom emacs display various themes in terminal

Tags: emacs

I employed the 'Ocean next theme' on alacritty terminal [Color schemes · jwilm/alacritty Wiki](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty/wiki/Color-schemes)

Upon starting doom-emacs from terminal (tmux new -s 'main'),

the identical commands `emacs -nw` display various theme.

[image]

I want the one above.

It's tricky that if start a new tmux session with other name saying 'focus',

They display the same themes

[image]

Restart the machine multiple times,

my desired theme appears on 'main' session to the above window.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your setup has too many layers:

Terminal->Tmux ->Emacs.

Try just running emacs without tmux (emacs has all the tmux goodies integrated) or better run the GUI emacs directly (themes will be in 100% full potential).

BTW, emacs GUI is not like GUI Vim. It's the total package if you run it with exwm.
Take out all decorations (scrool bar menu bar etc..) and it will look like a terminal app except with access to thousands of packages that cannot run in the terminal mode because of limitations.

Once you use it this way. There is no coming back.
My .xinitrc has one line exec emacs (keep in mind you can run firefox inside emacs)